# Parse Error response in Express NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am trying to send a specific error message to my front end.

## Scenario 1

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log(err);
});
```

*logs:*
`[String: 'Error: Request returned error code: 422 and body: {"status":422,"title":"Missing or incorrect required fields","type":"https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes","errors":{"variant":"This product has options, variant ID is required"}}']`

## Scenario 2

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.status(422).send('TEST TEST TEST');
});
```

[image]

## Scenario 3

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.status(422).send(err); //Same "err" as scenario 1
});
```

[image]

## Summary

In `scenarion 3` I expected to see what was logged in `scenario 1` on the frontend. Can someone help me send the `variant`  message (from scenario 1) to the frontend

Comment: do you get an answer yet or not?

Comment: not yet. I have a hunch and will try it on Monday

Comment: ok can you have some time then please post your code here I shall help you.

Comment: what is your frontend?

Comment: angular 5... what more can i provide?

Comment: ok so when you try to send specific error to frontend it will throw an error right and what is your front end application port?

Comment: scenario 2 and 3 show exactly what is happening on the front... this is a similar question not answered yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191271/cant-access-values-in-my-express-nodejs-response-error-string-error-reques/50191503#50191503

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170436/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-omar).